# "You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Tags: mysql, jdbc

The SQL query work fine in MySQL database, but when i use the same query in JDBC, I get:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Foods Ltd AND clsp_stockexchange=bse GROUP BY CLSP_DATEOFTRADE' at line 1

MySQL Version is 5.0. My jdbc code:

```java
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
String query = "SELECT  max(CLSP_DATEOFTRADE) AS TradeDate,CLSP_CLOSEPRICE FROM     stock.clccompany1 LEFT JOIN stock.clsp1 ON clccompany1.clcm_clsm_keyid=clsp1.clsp_clcm_keyid WHERE clcm_nameofthecompany=ADF Foods Ltd AND clsp_stockexchange=bse GROUP BY CLSP_DATEOFTRADE";
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet  rs = st.executeQuery(query);
while(rs.next())
{
    String s1=rs.getString(1);
    String s2=rs.getString(2);
    out.print(s1);
    out.print(s2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing issue with where clause

```
WHERE clcm_nameofthecompany = ADF Foods Ltd 
  AND clsp_stockexchange=bse 
GROUP BY CLSP_DATEOFTRADE
```

its need to wrap  ADF Foods Ltd with quotation. 
as

```
WHERE clcm_nameofthecompany = 'ADF Foods Ltd' 
     AND clsp_stockexchange=bse 
GROUP BY CLSP_DATEOFTRADE
```